# Hodge decomposition for complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a compact oriented Riemannian manifold. By Hodge decomposition, we can decompose

$$\Omega^k(X)=\mathrm{im}(d)\oplus\mathrm{im}(d^*)\oplus\ker(\Delta).$$

Now, if further $X$ has a complex structure, I read on a book that

$$\Omega^{p,q}(X)=\partial(\Omega^{p-1,q}(X))\oplus\partial^*(\Omega^{p+1,q}(X))\oplus\ker(\Delta_{\partial}),$$
or
$$\Omega^{p,q}(X)=\bar\partial(\Omega^{p,q-1}(X))\oplus\bar\partial^*(\Omega^{p,q+1}(X))\oplus\ker(\Delta_{\bar\partial}).$$

My question is: given that I know the theorem for the real case and $d=\partial+\bar\partial$, shouldn't the result be

$$\Omega^{p,q}(X)=(\partial(\Omega^{p-1,q}(X))+\bar\partial(\Omega^{p,q-1}(X)))\oplus(\partial^*(\Omega^{p+1,q}(X))+\bar\partial^*(\Omega^{p,q+1}(X)))\oplus\ker(\Delta)?$$

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, $\overline{\partial}\Omega^{p-1,q}(X) \subset \Omega^{p-1,q+1}(X)$.

Comment: @Mindlack You are right. I changed the indices.